Text not displaying when using USER_PATH instead of "F:" drive
I'm experiencing an issue with B&R Automation Studio where changing from "F:" drive to USER_PATH causes text not to display properly in the Panel Simulator.
Environment:

B&R Automation Studio
Using Panel Simulator
Project contains HMI visualization with text elements

Current Situation:
When running the simulation with partitions configured to use "F:" drive in the PLC configuration, everything works correctly - all text displays properly on the Panel Simulator.
Problem:
After switching from "F:" to USER_PATH (as recommended by B&R), the text on the Panel Simulator no longer displays. When switching back to "F:", the text displays correctly again.
What I've Tried:

Configured USER_PATH in the CPU configuration
Updated partition mapping to use USER_PATH instead of "F:"
Rebuilt and transferred the project

Example
File device:
F:\Recipe\RecipeTypes -> (Works).
Now it should work replacing it with USER_PATH:
USER_PATH\Recipe\RecipeTypes -> (Doesn't work)
Question:
What could be causing the text not to display when using USER_PATH, and how can I resolve this while still using USER_PATH instead of "F:"?

Is the USER_PATH properly configured in the project’s CPU configuration, and does it point to the exact directory where the text resources are stored for the HMI?

It seems to be correctly configured, as USER_PATH works on the physical Main Panel. However, it's unclear what USER_PATH specifically points to. According to B&R documentation, USER_PATH typically maps to \WorkingPath\USER, where WorkingPath is set to \Proj\Temp\Simulation\Config\Cpu. Based on this, the working path seems correct, but I haven't found a method to explicitly check where USER_PATH is pointing in the file system. How can I check that?

If you have not copied your files to a proper folder, then it is clear why it doesn’t work for you.
USER_PATH is a system variable that can be used to access the user partition on the system to store data. Instead of using a drive letter, USER_PATH can be used to access the user partition on all target systems (including ARsim) regardless of the actual partitioning. In ARsim, the directory corresponding to USER_PATH is found at <WorkingPath>\USER\.
So in short,the folder for USER_PATH accessed by ArSim, you can find in the Temp folder of your project here:
\<ProjectFolder>\Temp\Simulation\<configurationName>\<PLCname>\USER

Source: https://help.br-automation.com/#/en/4/automationruntime/operationmethode/moduledatasec/userpartition.html
